# Visible='<%# UserCanEdit %>' – if set to true inside Page_Load, then control isn't visible

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, data-binding, gridview

User control defines a property named *UserCanEdit*:

```
private bool _userCanEdit=false;
public bool UserCanEdit
{
    get { return _userCanEdit; }
    set { _userCanEdit = value; }
}
```

This User Control also contains the following *GridView*:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="C" runat="server" Visible='<%# UserCanEdit %>' Text="Visibility"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

For control *C* to be visible, *UserCanEdit* needs to be set to *true*. If I set it inside *Page_Init()*, then *C* is indeed visible. But if I set it inside *Page_Load()*, then *C* is not visible:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.UserCanEdit = (this.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated &&
       (this.Page.User.IsInRole("Administrators") ||
        this.Page.User.IsInRole("Editors")));

    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

So why isn’t *C* visible if *UserCanEdit* is set inside Page_Load()? As far as I know, single-value binding expression *<%#%>* is evaluated only when *GridView.DataBind()* is called, which happens after *UserCanEdit* is set to *true*?!

cheers

Comment: Can you pleas tell me what is DataSource for GridView1?

Comment: I ommited some code in my post(for clarity), but it's actually bound to ObjectDataSource,where Select method returns string[]

Comment: Have you tried creating a handler for the RowDataBound event, and placing a breakpoint there?  I'm curious as to the answer of this as well.  Rendering doesn't take place until AFTER Page_Load is fired, so I would think this should work.  Also, did you try changing "<%# UserCanEdit %>" to "<%= UserCanEdit %>"?  Not sure why you would need this in a binding expression.

Comment: uhm, it works now. I simply turned on computer and started the VS and for some reason it's working now. I haven't done any programming since yesterday, so it's a bit of a mistery as to why it is working now. Sorry for taking your time

Answer (score 2):

My guess is because the controls are being defined before you have a value for UserCanEdit yet.  Wouldn't the controls be loaded before the Page_Load() in the Page Initialization step?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: Here's a follow up article to Mark's suggestion
http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020102.htm

Comment: I understand page's lifecycle. Controls indeed are initialized prior to Page_Load(), but that doesn't mean you can't change control's properties after they are initialized ( thus inside Page_Load() ).

Answer (score 1):

I guess issue over here is UserCanEdit is not part your datasource for gridview. How can you Bind based on Property which is not part of your source. I guess what you are trying to do is you want to hide a column based on some user credential. Possible sulution would be user OnRowDataBound event. And inside that event user something like this

if(Condition)

```
((Label)e.Row.FindControl("C")).visible = true;
```

else

```
((Label)e.Row.FindControl("C")).visible = false;
```

Now you can set this codition inside actual Page_Load(Your web page) event.

Note: Condition is actully public property similar to your UserCanEdit